Google OAuth2.0 Callback on Java Spring returning different redirect_uri
I'm currently developing a program that using google sheet API to get some data. I tried deploying it onto Amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux) and configured SSL using Let's Encrpyt. Everything is working fine until I have to authorise myself to use the API (it worked in local environment because the callback was just http://localhost:8080/Callback). I redirected the EC2 IP to a domain name called https://example.com and changed my redirect_uri to https://example.com:8888/Callback.
Now when I run the spring application, it generates a link but the redirect_uri is set to http://example.com:8888/Callback (it is supposed to be https), which just brings me to Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch. I tried hard coding the redirect_uri (to https://example.com:8888/Callback) but even though it brings me to select a user, it ultimately brings me to the same error.
Here is the application.properties (I have removed the sensitive information)
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=/path/to/my/key-store
server.ssl.key-store-password=my-password
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=https://example.com:8888/Callback

and this is the code I'm running
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
        .setHost("example.com")
        .setPort(8888)
        .setCallbackPath("/Callback")
        .build();

Initially I thought it was because port 8888 was not configured, but I tried setting it up using Nginx and it got worse. Even my main page would not load. At this point I'm not sure whether it's because I set up the LocalServerReceiver wrongly or because of some networking issues. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance!

This would be an outside-the-box solution, but for your use case isn't a solution like Zerosheets faster to implement?
You get a simple GET endpoint for your sheet, if reading information is all you need.
